# How to specify an Express Route with any string after /reset/

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I am building a Node/Express.js webapp and I dont want any user of the webapp to access pages other than index, forgot-pass and reset without logging in. I am using this reset route for resetting password. So I am sending a random token after /reset/ (E.g: ../reset/4c1ff3ada180bea9da6333fd9555dd100828d530). I have set up a basic middle-ware for restricting access to other pages without login.

This is my middle-ware.

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');

module.exports = {
    isLoginCheck : function (request, response, next) {
      if(!request.session.user && request.path != '/index' && request.path != '/forgot-pass' && request.path != '/forgot' && request.path != '/reset/*'){
         response.redirect('/index');
      }else{
         next();
      }
   },
};
```

But /reset/* is not matching with my routes, therefore throws me back to the index page. I need to send the token after /reset/, so that I can query the database for resetting password.

So how can I specify any random string after /reset/?

This is my router for /reset.

```
router.get('/reset/:token', indexController.pagesReset);
```

Comment: So you basically want to capture `tom3jlke` from `/reset/tom3jlke` f. e. ?

Comment: Yes I am capturing tom3jike(In your example) in the "token".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your condition, the path (in case you are on `/reset/egze5g` is not `/reset/*` but `/reset/egze5g`.

You can replace this condition by a regex: `request.path.match(/\/reset\/[\w]+/)`

Just in case: you could clean your code by replacing your awfull line full of conditions by just

`if (!request.session.user && !['/index', '/forgot-pass', '/forgot'].includes(request.path) && !request.path.match(/\/reset\/[\w+]/)){`

Comment: If I do exactly what you have told then I am getting,
_'/\/reset\/*/.match_ is not a function'.

If I use `!'/\/reset\/*/'.match(request.path)` - this, Then it keeps happening the same thing which is getting back to the index page.

Comment: sorry, I wrote it wrong, I'm editing my post right now

Comment: Its works! Thank you for helping. Just one more little detail, It will be `!request.path.match(/\/reset\/[\w+]/)` instead of `req` for my answer. Again, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

This Regex captures everything after `/reset/` .

```
(?:\/reset\/)(.+)
```

```js
var myString = "/reset/fhlkejg234hk";
var myRegexp = /(?:\/reset\/)(.+)/g;
var token = myRegexp.exec(myString)[1];
console.log(token);
```

Comment: Please specify, I have tried `request.path != '(?:\/reset\/)(.+)'` but it didn't work, same as before..

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Laurent, but It will over complicate my code. I've got the solution. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For better scaling try something like this

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');

let app = express();

app.use('/users/:user_id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.user_id);
    res.send(req.params.user_id);
});

app.use(["/index","/forgot"], function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("For index")
    res.send("For index/forgot")
});

app.use("/", function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("For all other links")
    res.send("For all other links")
});

app.listen("2010",()=>console.log("Server at 2010"));
```

Please refer https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html for creating middleware in express